# Skip validation on a particular field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am looking for a way to skip validation on a field. Currently i have a form in which we have required fields. However salesforce prioritizes Front end validation errors, and thus validation rules don't occur at all. The problem is i have a datefield that requires alteration of some other fields for months. The date field will just increment the date using the months. However what happens is Invalid Date occurs, and i made the datefield read only.

Is there anyway to fix my validation problem or am i forced to back end triggers for everything?

Comment: I am not sure what Front End validations means. In SFDC you can make fields required at the data layer via Validation Rules and Required = true on a field. You can also make fields required view only by updateing the standard page layout and setting Reqiured = True for the field.

Comment: Are you using a standard page layout or is this a Visualforce Page? Visualforce page tags have attributes also which can skip validation (immediate=true) however they have side effects that can cause issues also (setters not firing). Can you provide more details on what your exact use case and issue is?

Comment: Check my answer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22213/how-can-i-dynamically-render-required-fields-using-a-dynamic-component or any other examples of `<apex:actionRegion>` usage for partial form submission and rerender of the section you're interested in. That way the full page validation with all required fields can occur later when somebody clicks commandButton and whole form will be submitted.